# Laravel eloquent join multiple table and search data using with() method

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have two table user and user_info. I need to join those table and have to search data from them. It is throwing error as unknown column.I have solution using DB query, Is it possible to do search using with() method in controller and eloquent relationship in model.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use for example: `DB::table('users')->join('user_info','user_info.id_user','=','users.id_user')->get()`. Check it out and write back.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to filter models by their related models attributes using **with()** - this method only allows filtering related models, not the original ones you're loading.

In order to filter by attributes of related models you should use **whereHas()** method, e.g. in order to load all users that have **country** column set to **uk** in their **user_info** data you could do the following:

```
$usersFromUK = User::with('user_info')->whereHas('user_info', function($query) {
  $query->whereCountry('uk');
})->get();
```